# Unale to use apache server because of norton 360

Tags: php, apache, norton

I have been trying this port 80 issues for a few days now. I have try everything from uninstalling skype and varies other programs that might be using port 80. I did `netstat -ano | find ":80"` and I found that PID of `1692` I looked this up in task manager and  it was `Norton 360` I have paid for a few years license for this. so I can't uninstall it.

I have search on Google and I haven't found any topic about this which can help me fix this. Please any ideas what I should do now? 
Thanks

Comment: [lmgtfy](https://www.google.com/search?q=norton+360+open+port)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify the port, don't use port 80 any more, use 8080, do the same thing as following: open the file httpd.conf, and find the string "Listen 80", change 80 to 8080 then save the file, and then resart httpd service.
When you use 8080, you can access the page by this way: `http://localhost/test.php:8080.`

Comment: I read from a few forums that xampp is really bad and wamp is not that good either and few people in that forum recommended Uniform server so I am trying that now